# Calling a function parallelly that does internal parallelization?

Tags: python, parallel-processing

**MAJOR EDIT**

Suppose I have a function that does internal parallelization, and I want to parallelize this function. How do I do this in Python?

Let's consider a very simple concrete example.

The function `fun1` takes two numbers as input and adds them up.

```
def fun1(a, b):
 return a+b
```

The function `fun2` takes two integer inputs `m` and `n`. It generates a list of size mn containing tuples as the following code shows. Then it parallelizes `fun1` on this list.

```
def fun2(m, n):

 # create list of mn tuples
 list_tuple = [(i, j) for i in range(m) for j in range(n)]

 # apply fun1 parallelly to list_tuple

 pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
 return pool.starmap(fun1, list_tuple)
```

Thus, `fun2` returns a list of size mn. We want to apply `fun2` parallelly to a list of (m,n) pairs.

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
 # create the list of (m, n) tuples
 list_tuple = [(m, n) for m in range(10) for n in range(10)]

 # parallellize fun2
 pool = multiprocessing.Pool()
 pool.starmap(fun2, list_tuple)
```

My questions:

1. Can I write everything above in the same script?
2. If answer to 1 is yes, what is the correct way to write it? For example should there be `if __name__ == 'main'` inside the definition of `fun2` as well?
3. If answer to 1 is no, then how to write this correctly in two scripts?

I am a beginner at parallelization and don't yet understand how the threads are connected so help is highly appreciated.

Thanks!

Comment: Did you try running that code? If you did you might have noticed "AssertionError: daemonic processes are not allowed to have children"

Comment: Exactly I got this error and I am not sure what to do.